# Android async progress dialog delayed

Tags: android, progress, android-progressbar

I have a progress dialog class that is a subclass of my main activity. Which in itself runs fine.

```
public class UpdateFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog loading;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(NewsFeedActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        loading.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have a method called getNews which sends a http post request and parses the result, this takes a few seconds. In this method I call the UpdateFeedTask to show the progress dialog asynchronously, but it doesn't appear to do it simultaneously. The progress dialog seems to open only after the http request is completed so instead of showing the progress dialog and sending the request it appears to complete the method getNews first and then briefly shows the progress dialog after for a split second. How can I make the dialog show before I fetch the data? Here is how I call the progress dialog

```
public void getNews(){

            //show the progress dialog
    new UpdateFeedTask().execute();


    //go fetch some data
    WheruClient newsFeedLocation = new WheruClient();

    try {

        newsFeedArray = newsFeedLocation.getLocationActivity(sessionKey,page,filter,when);


    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT new async class sends http request in background and gets back json array, but I get a fatal error that reads

04-07 15:33:02.967: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11004): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I read your examples and I think im missing something about doing work in the background, any thoughts?

```
public class UpdateFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        //loading = ProgressDialog.show(NewsFeedActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

        //loading.dismiss();
        updateFeed(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {

        WheruClient newsFeedLocation = new WheruClient();

        try {
            newsFeedArray = newsFeedLocation.getLocationActivity(sessionKey,page,filter,when);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newsFeedArray;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time intensive task needs to be called in doInBackground. I see nothing in your doInBackground method. Beware, do not touch the UI in doInBackground. I have some sample code [here.](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/asynch)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the structure around to do the work in the doInBackground method. It now appears to open the progress dialog, go fetch the json array but quickly crashes after. Not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Brian Perin Perhaps the call in doInBackground is throwing an exception in the thread. I would wrap the call in doInBackground into a try catch e and Log.d(TAG,"msg",e) to see what is crashing the app.